# laravel collective checkbox form

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-5, forms, laravelcollective

I'm trying to implement checkbox and laravel collective in my form but I get only single value in form, any ideas how to fix it

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>'UserController@updateInfo','method'=>'post')) !!}
 Workdays:
<br>
{!! Form::label('monday', 'Monday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'monday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('tuesday', 'Tuesday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'tuesday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('wednesday', 'Wednesday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'wednesday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('thursday', 'Thursday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'thursday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('friday', 'Friday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'friday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('saturday', 'Saturday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'saturday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('sunday', 'Sunday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday', 'sunday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::submit('Save', $attributes = ['class'=>'button']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

when I print my request i only get single output (eg. selected monday friday I get only friday when request is processed)

also labels not working - ideas on that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the same name (workday) for all your checkboxes. That's why it's only showing the last checkbox with that name

Just change all names to workday[] instead.

```
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'monday') !!}
```

This will return all selected checkbox in an array.

Comment: thanks it works... didn't expect that I need set array, thanks.
any idea howto set labels

Comment: Your labels seems to be fine. What are you getting?

Comment: if you're having any further issues you can refer to these sites:

[laravel recipes: labels](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/154/creating-a-form-label-element) or
[laravel docs: labels](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#labels)

Comment: labels are there but when i click them checkbox is not clicked, I need to click on checkbox in order to select item, can't click text for checkbox toggle

Comment: labels are linked to the `id` of the checkbox, not the `name`. Just add an `id` on your checkbox same with the name of your label:
    `{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'sunday', null, ['id' => 'sunday']) !!}`

Comment: Don't forget to add `null` on the third argument

Comment: love it works, thanks on reference for laravel recipes, have useful stuffs there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
You used same name for every `checkbox` when you `checked` multiple `checkbox` you only get the last value.

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>'UserController@updateInfo','method'=>'post')) !!}
 Workdays:
<br>
{!! Form::label('monday', 'Monday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'monday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('tuesday', 'Tuesday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'tuesday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('wednesday', 'Wednesday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'wednesday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('thursday', 'Thursday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'thursday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('friday', 'Friday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'friday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('saturday', 'Saturday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'saturday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::label('sunday', 'Sunday') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'sunday') !!}
<br>
{!! Form::submit('Save', $attributes = ['class'=>'button']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using the same name (workday) for all your checkboxes. That's why it's only showing the last checkbox with that name

```
{{ Form::checkbox('workday[]', 'monday') }}
```